# Python why numpy linspace gives me floats between two integers with uneven difference

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to generate a list of values between the two values. For example, I need a list of 10 values between 1 and 2 including both.

My code and output:

```
idf_list = np.linspace(1,2,10)
print(idf_list)
Out[14]: 
array([1.        , 1.11111111, 1.22222222, 1.33333333, 1.44444444,
       1.55555556, 1.66666667, 1.77777778, 1.88888889, 2.        ])
```

I am surprised by looking at the my present output because I was expecting something like below.

My expected output:

```
print(idf_list)
array([1,1.1,1.2,......,1.8,1.9,2])
```

Is numpy linspace wrong to use? or am I use it wrongly? How to get my expected output?

Comment: You want 11 samples, not 10

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci Oho! you were right. I miss judged it. I should put 11, not 10 to get what I wanted. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you want is inclusive of both end points. Thus length 11, not 10

```
>>> idf_list = np.linspace(1,2,11)
>>> idf_list
array([ 1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ])
>>> len(idf_list)
11
```